# $_POST not retrieving data from Javascript's Fetch()

Tags: javascript, php, post

I'm posting data using javascript's `fetch()` .

```
    fetch('/string.php', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'helloe world',
      })
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.text()
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
```

string.php file contains:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Now my problem is the `$_POST` returns an empty array. I can fix this by appending the file with:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

But that feels very hackish and isn't ideal. Is this the intended behaviour for PHP when retrieving post data from a JS `fetch()`?

Is there anyway I may automatically put the contents within the `$_POST`?

Comment: Looks correct to me, you're sending a request body of a string, not multi-part form data.

Comment: Removing the `json.stringify` is less hackish than parsing the php://input

Comment: Thank you. This question gives me the answer to my question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$_POST` is only populated by `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` requests.

For any other data format, you will need to parse `php://input` manually. In your case, you're using `json_decode` and putting the result in the `$_POST` superglobal, which is an acceptable way to "convert" from JSON to form data.

Comment: You should re-phrase the first sentence. Sounds pretty wrong to me (it is correct, but it's badly worded). ;)

Answer (score 5):

> But that feels very hackish and isn't ideal.

Assigning to `$_POST` is a bit weird. It is generally treated as read only. Most people would use another variable.

You should set the Content-Type on the request though, `fetch` will default to claiming a string is plain text unless you tell it otherwise.

> Is this the intended behaviour for PHP when retrieving post data from a JS fetch()?

No. It is the intended behaviour when PHP doesn't support the content-type of the request body.

> Is there anyway I may automatically put the contents within the $_POST?

Send form encoded or multipart data instead of JSON encoded data.

Comment: Since when is `$_POST` read-only? Badly worded if you ask me, since you probably meant that the variable itself isn't read-only but most people don't override the `$_POST` variable or its content and rather assign it to a new variable.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois — That's why I said "treated as" and not "is"